# Fixing misshaped GeoJSON polygons

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, geometry, web-mercator, ghana

In 2018 Ghana changed its administrative divisions (from 11 to 16 regions, and from 216 to 260 districts). Unfortunately, I have not been able to find the GeoJSON (or equivalent) data for the new divisions. I managed to scrape map data from a website I will not name, by looking into AJAX requests. Except the coordinates of the regions were using the Web Mercator system (ESPG:3857).

I coded a small script to convert them into Lon/Lat (CRS:84) and build a GeoJSON file, and here is the result:

[image: faulty polygons]

Some polygons appear to overlap each other. I believe this may be caused by the massive lake in the center of the country (and also the smaller one in the south east). I thought maybe my conversion was off so I tried generating my GeoJSON without converting the coordinates, and the result is the same.

What is wrong with my data and how can I fix it?

Is there a script I can use to remove points that are outliers?

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @SpacedMan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374122/fixing-misshaped-geojson-polygons/433727#comment611299_374122):

> That looks fairly hard to recover, and might be due to a number of
> things. OpenStreetMap seems to have 16 admin-level "4" subdivisions
> for Ghana that look like your map except they don't follow the lake,
> instead dividing the lake into parts. You can extract the data using
> Overpass (which I've done and imported into QGIS).
> http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Y2v (run query, export to geojson, load in
> QGIS, crop polygons to Ghana).